# two dimensional vector matrices addition

Tags: c++

```
vector<vector<int>> AsumB(
    int kolumny, vector<vector<int>> matrix1, vector<vector<int>> matrix2) {
    vector<vector<int>>matrix(kolumny);
    matrix = vector<vector<int>>(matrix1.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < kolumny; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; i <(static_cast<signed int>(matrix1.size())); ++i)
            matrix[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] + matrix2[i][j];

     return matrix;
}
```

Please tell me what I don't understand and help me solve this problem
because for 1dimensional vector this kind of description would work;

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active)  no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>" to "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>>>>" exists lab4

Comment: @CezaryCzekalski What line does that error appear on? If you could add it to the question that would probably make it a more clear question.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
vector<vector<int>> AsumB(vector<vector<int>> const & matrix1,
                          vector<vector<int>> const & matrix2) {
    vector<vector<int>> matrix(matrix1);
    for (std::size_t i = 0U; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
        for (std::size_t j = 0U; j < matrix[j].size(); ++j)
            matrix[i][j] += matrix2[i][j];

    return matrix;
}
```

?

Comment: Save yourself a bit of code and pass in `matrix1` by value. Let the compiler do the copy for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce, and OP's reported compiler error doesn't look like it matches the code, so the problem is probably somewhere else.

However, there is a lot wrong here that could be causing all sorts of bad that should be addressed. I've taken the liberty of reformatting the code a bit to make explaining easier

```
vector<vector<int>> AsumB(int kolumny,
                          vector<vector<int>> matrix1,
                          vector<vector<int>> matrix2)
```

`matrix1` and `matrix2` are passed by value. There is nothing wrong logically, but this means there is the potential for a lot of unnecessary copying unless the compiler is very sharp.

```
{
    vector<vector<int>> matrix(kolumny);
```

Declares a `vector` of `vector`s with the outer `vector` sized to `kolumny`. There are no inner `vector`s allocated, so 2D operations are doomed.

```
    matrix = vector<vector<int>>(matrix1.size());
```

Makes a temporary `vector` of `vector`s with the outer `vector` sized to match the outer vector of `matrix1`. This temporary vector is then assigned to the just created `matrix`, replacing it's current contents, and is then destroyed. `matrix` still has no inner vectors allocated, so 2D operations are still doomed.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < kolumny; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; i < (static_cast<signed int>(matrix1.size())); ++i)
```

`i` and `j` should never go negative (huge logic problem if they do), so use an unsigned type. Use the right unsigned type and the `static_cast` is meaningless.

In addition the inner `for` loop increments and tests `i`, not `j`

```
            matrix[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] + matrix2[i][j];
```

I see nothing wrong here other than `matrix` having nothing for `j` to index. This will result in [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as access go out of bounds.

```
    return matrix;
}
```

Cleaning this up so that it is logically sound:

```
vector<vector<int>> AsumB(const vector<vector<int>> & matrix1,
                          const vector<vector<int>> & matrix2)
```

We don't need the number of columns. The vector already knows all the sizes involved. A caveat, though: `vector<vector<int>>` allows different sizes of all of the inner `vector`s. Don't do this and you should be good.

Next, this function now takes parameters by constant reference.. With the reference there is no copying. With `const` the compiler knows the vectors will not be changed insode the function and can prevent errors and make a bunch of optimizations.

```
{
    size_t row = matrix1.size();
```

`size_t` is an unsigned data type guaranteed to be large enough to index any representable object. It will be bg enough and you don't have to worry about pesky negaitve numbers. Also eliminates the need for any casting later.

```
    if (!(row > 0 && row == matrix2.size()))
    {
        return  vector<vector<int>>();
    }
```

Here we make sure that everyone agrees ont he number of rows inviolved and return an empty `vector` if they don't. You could also throw an exception. The exception may be a better solution, but I don't know the use case.

```
    size_t column = matrix1[0].size();
    if (!(column > 0 && column == matrix2[0].size()))
    {
        return  vector<vector<int>>();
    }
```

Dowes the same as above, but makes sure the number of columns makes sense.

```
    vector<vector<int>> matrix(row, vector<int>(column));
```

Created a local row by column matrix to store the result. Note the second parameter. `vector<int>(column)` tells the compiler that all `row` inner vectors will be initialized to a `vector` of size `column`.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j)
        {
```

Here we simplified the loops just a bit since we know all the sizes.

```
            matrix[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] + matrix2[i][j];
        }
    }

    return matrix;
```

The compiler has a number of tricks at its disposal to eliminate copying matrix on return. Look up Return Value Optimization with your preferred web search engine if you want to know more.
    }

All together:

```
vector<vector<int>> AsumB(const vector<vector<int>> & matrix1,
                          const vector<vector<int>> & matrix2)
{
    size_t row = matrix1.size();
    if (!(row > 0 && row == matrix2.size()))
    {
        return  vector<vector<int>>();
    }
    size_t column = matrix1[0].size();
    if (!(column > 0 && column == matrix2[0].size()))
    {
        return  vector<vector<int>>();
    }
    vector<vector<int>> matrix(row, vector<int>(column));

    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; ++j)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] + matrix2[i][j];
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```